# Magento : file size limit in Varien_File_Uploader

Tags: php, magento, file-upload

I am uploading image files using Varien_File_Uploader, i can set allowed file extensions but can i set file size limit ?

My code is

```
$uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('editimg');
$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
$uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
$uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS ;
$uploader->save($path, $imfname);
```

i know that i can put file size limit from php.ini, but is there any function in Varien_File_Uploader for file size ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't any related function in `Varien_File_Uploader`, but you can use `Varien_File_Uploader::addValidateCallback($callbackName, $callbackObject, $callbackMethod)` to add your own validation method based on the file size, which will be sent the value of `$_FILES['editimg']['tmp_name']`

Comment: Example use in Magento core: Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_File::_beforeSave() line 64